# not able to parse the ansible output

Tags: ansible

I am not able to parse ansible folwing output. trying to get the ip address.

I am trying to get ip address of azure vm, to get the ip. I am using the azure_rm_networkinterface_facts module, in this module I am feeding the nic name, which stored in used the diet.

Here is my output, which i want to parse.

```
ok: [
  localhost
]=>(item={
  'value': [
    u'datamover-nic10'
  ],
  'key': u'data-mover'
})=>{
  "ansible_facts": {
    "azure_networkinterfaces": [
      {
        "etag": "W/\"08842209-be15-1144f26\"",
        "id": "/subscriptions/1cf78a5c-5a30--c52c2d3d21b6/resourceGroups/DEVT/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/datamover-nic10",
        "location": "westus",
        "name": "datamover-nic10",
        "properties": {
          "dnsSettings": {
            "appliedDnsServers": [

            ],
            "dnsServers": [

            ],
            "internalDomainNameSuffix": "3endvnfzb.dx.internal.cloudapp.net"
          },
          "enableAcceleratedNetworking": false,
          "enableIPForwarding": false,
          "ipConfigurations": [
            {
              "etag": "W/\"088421144f26\"",
              "id": "/subscriptions/1cf78a52c2d3d21b6/resourceGroups/DEVT/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/datamover-nic10/ipConfigurations/ip1",
              "name": "ip1",
              "properties": {
                "primary": true,
                "privateIPAddress": "10.172.240.11",
                "privateIPAddressVersion": "IPv4",
                "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Static",
                "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                "subnet": {
                  "id": "/subscriptions/1cf78a5c-5ac2d3d21b6/resourceGroups/DEVT/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vNetOne/subnets/vmsubnet"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "macAddress": "00-0D-3A-36-B3-5C",
          "networkSecurityGroup": {
            "id": "/subscriptions/1cf78ad3d21b6/resourceGroups/DEVT/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/datamover-nsg"
          },
          "primary": true,
          "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
          "resourceGuid": "03114",
          "virtualMachine": {
            "id": "/subscriptions/1cf7d3d21b6/resourceGroups/DEVT/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/datamover"
          }
        },
        "tags": {
          "component": "datamover",
          "provider": "B50E5F"
        },
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces"
      }
    ]
  },
  "changed": false,
  "item": {
    "key": "data-mover",
    "value": [
      "datamover-nic10"
    ]
  }
}ok: [
  localhost
]=>(item={
  'value': [
    u'database-nic00'
  ],
  'key': u'database'
})=>{
  "ansible_facts": {
    "azure_networkinterfaces": [
      {
        "etag": "W/\"60bfd8c17323612\"",
        "id": "/subscriptions/1cf72d3d21b6/resourceGroups/DEVT/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/database-nic00",
        "location": "westus",
        "name": "database-nic00",
        "properties": {
          "dnsSettings": {
            "appliedDnsServers": [

            ],
            "dnsServers": [

            ],
            "internalDomainNameSuffix": "3wjfzb.dx.internal.cloudapp.net"
          },
          "enableAcceleratedNetworking": false,
          "enableIPForwarding": false,
          "ipConfigurations": [
            {
              "etag": "W/\"603612\"",
              "id": "/subscriptions/1c2d3d21b6/resourceGroups/DEVT/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/database-nic00/ipConfigurations/ip1",
              "name": "ip1",
              "properties": {
                "primary": true,
                "privateIPAddress": "10.172.240.4",
                "privateIPAddressVersion": "IPv4",
                "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Static",
                "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                "subnet": {
                  "id": "/subscriptions/1c3d21b6/resourceGroups/DEVT/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vNetOne/subnets/vmsubnet"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "etag": "W/\"60b3612\"",
              "id": "/subscriptions/1cfd3d21b6/resourceGroups/DEVT/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/database-nic00/ipConfigurations/ip2",
              "name": "ip2",
              "properties": {
                "primary": false,
                "privateIPAddress": "10.172.0.6",
                "privateIPAddressVersion": "IPv4",
                "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Static",
                "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                "subnet": {
                  "id": "/subscriptions/1d3d21b6/resourceGroups/DEVT/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vNetOne/subnets/vmsubnet"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "macAddress": "00-0D-3A-36-BC-FB",
          "networkSecurityGroup": {
            "id": "/subscriptions/1cf52c2d3d21b6/resourceGroups/ImcSite-UPAASDEVT/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/database-nsg"
          },
          "primary": true,
          "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
          "resourceGuid": "4d2fd4441e3c",
          "virtualMachine": {
            "id": "/subscriptions/1cf7d3d21b6/resourceGroups/DEVT/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/database-vm0"
          }
        },
        "tags": {
          "component": "database",
          "provider": "B52B9A0E5F"
        },
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces"
      }
    ]
  },
  "changed": false,
  "item": {
    "key": "database",
    "value": [
      "database-nic00"
    ]
  }
}
```

I am trying to parse and get 10.172.240.11 and 10.172.240.4 address from the output using the following method.  Can you please someone help me on this?

```
- debug: msg=" {{ item.value[0] }}"
  with_dict:
        - "{{ vm_net_intf }}"
```

I expect to print 10.172.240.11 and 10.172.240.4 ip address in debug

Answer (score 0):

With the last part of the *ansible_facts* the play below below

```
tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item.properties.ipConfigurations|
               json_query('[].properties.privateIPAddress') }}"
    loop: "{{ ansible_facts.azure_networkinterfaces }}"
```

gives (abridged):

```
"msg": [
    "10.172.240.4", 
    "10.172.0.6"
]
```